# group join error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

I need to fetch all non-deleted profiles, amounts of successful and overall activations. The key (which connects profiles with logs is 'DeviceClass' field). I came up with the following LINQ to SQL query:

```
var v = from profile in repositoryProfiles.GetAll()
    join logsCounted in
        (
        from log in repositoryLogs.GetAll()
        where log.OperationType == EnrollmentLog.OperationTypeEnum.EnrollDevice
        group log by log.DeviceClass into logs
        select new
        {
            DeviceClass = logs.Key, 
            SuccessfulAmount = logs.Where(log=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(log.Error)).Count(), 
            OverallAmount = logs.Count()
        }
        ) on profile.DeviceClass equals logsCounted.DeviceClass
    where profile.Deleted==false
    select new
    {
        Profile = profile,
        SuccessAmount = logsCounted.SuccessfulAmount,
        TotalAmount = logsCounted.OverallAmount
    };
```

Attempting to call `v.ToList()` causes the following error:

```
Member access 'System.String Key' of  
'System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,CMCore.Data.Logging.IEnrollmentLog]'  
not legal on type  
'System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,CMCore.Data.Logging.EnrollmentLog].
```

**Question 1**: What is wrong with 'Key' property access?

**Question 2**: How could I implement the above mentioned idea?

**EDIT:**

The simplified version:

```
        var v1 = from log in repositoryLogs.GetAll()
                 group log by log.DeviceClass
                 into logs
                 select new
                            {
                                DeviceClass = logs.Key
                            };
        var logsGroupped = v1.ToList();
```

causes the same error... :(

Comment: disregard previous comment :)

Comment: :) ok, so disregarded my comment to it too :)

Comment: but, just for history and ... 'repositoryLogs.GetAll()' returns list of 'IEnrollmentLog' objects. but inner query should return list of anonymous type objects with properties 'DeviceClass', 'SuccessfulAmount', and 'OverallAmount'. 'logs' list obtained by logs grouping on 'log.DeviceClass' field should be a list of 'IEnrollmentLog', and this 'logs' should has a 'Key' property... that should represent grouped 'DeviceClass' value...

Comment: System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,CMCore.Data.Logging.IEnrollmentLog] <-- it looks like you are trying define an interface (which isn't allowed) where a class is needed as the type in brackets

Comment: I'm assuming `DeviceClass` is a `string`.  Does it work in your simplified example if you change what you are grouping to just the error strings?  `... group log.Error by log.DeviceClass into logs ...`

Comment: It doesn't work if I will use any other field (integer, ...).

Comment: Guess, the problem is that "repositoryLogs.GetAll()". the 'repositoryLogs' is not a DBContext object. It is my custom implementation that returns my IQueryable. I've tried to execute similar query using DBContext object (actual table that contains data) - everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
    var v1 = from log in repositoryLogs.GetAll()
             group log by log.DeviceClass
             into logs
             select new
                        {
                            DeviceClass = logs.First().DeviceClass
                        };
    var classes = v1.ToList();
```